# Existence of Non-negative Solution for Special Linear Equation System

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, matrix-equations

I have to deal with the following linear equation system:

\begin{align}
&\boldsymbol{A} \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}, \text{ s.t.} \\
&\boldsymbol{A} \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq0}^{n \times n}, \forall i,j \in \{1, \dots, n\}: A_{ii} = 0, A_{ij} > 0 \text{ if } i \neq j,\\
&\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n_{\geq0},\\
&\mathbf{b} = \begin{bmatrix} c \\ \vdots \\ c \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}^n.
\end{align}

My question is: Which properties must matrix $\mathbf{A}$ have such that we obtain a valid solution $\mathbf{x} \geq \mathbf{0}$ for the above described linear equation system?

For $n=1$, no solution exists. For $n=2$, there always exists a solution, namely $x_1 = \frac{c}{A_{21}} > 0$ and $x_2 = \frac{c}{A_{12}} > 0$.

I am looking forward to reading your replies.

Comment: What did you obtain for $n=1$ and $n=2$? Don't forget to write what you have tried so far.

Comment: Good point. I added my solutions to the above question.